# Desktop icons on windows xp go back to unordered state after restart

Tags: windows-xp, desktop

I am using windows XP align to grid property.
Then i arrange them in my order.

But when i restart all icons again goes to their previous state. What should i do

Comment: Are you in a corporate environment? Are you an administrator on the local computer?

Comment: Its my home computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn off Auto Arrange. Turn off Align to Grid.

Comment: If he had those set, he would not be able to move them in the first place.